# Using AsNoTracking in Entity Framework 6 to clone entity with manytomany, database first

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, clone

I want to clone an entity which has manytomany-relationship(s) and possibly also regular foreign key relationships, I'm doing database first so I don't think serialization is possible, right? I don't want to edit code that's generated.

Let's call the database tables A, B and AToB, where AToB is just a ManyToMany mapping table from A to B.

I've managed to clone an independent entity (before adding B and AToB) like this:

```
var myA = context.A.AsNoTracking().First();
myA.Id = 0; // this is changed automatically since the column is auto incrementing, but I need to change it to avoid conflicts
context.Entry(myA).State = EntityState.Added;
context.A.Attach(myA);
context.SaveChanges();
```

This works, and I also think I could get the foreign key case work with a bit more work since B is an entity itself, that can be copied just like I did with A above.

However, when I add B and AToB and update my model from the database, I get an error as expected:

```
{"Unable to update the EntitySet 'AToB' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation."}
```

From a database perspective, what I want to do is to copy the rows in AToB that point to myA, change the AIds to the Id of the copy, and keep the BIds. But I don't see how to do that using entity framework. Is it possible? How? Since AToB is not an entity but just a relationship in my model, I can't do something like context.AToB.AsNoTracking().

Comment: You leave out the most important part. How do you add B and AToB?

Comment: I add it as database tables, adding foreign keys in AToB, then I update my model through the "Update model from database..." wizard, adding the tables and clicking ok. Not doing any manual changes to the model.

Comment: Does your relation have any data? i.e. is AToB reified with a dedicated class on the C# side or A and B reference each other through collections?

Comment: In other words: please show the essential parts of the class model. It matters a lot what the associations look like.